# Conditional distribution of a Gaussian process is a Gaussian?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

$Y(\mathbf{X})$ is a Gaussian process denoted as $\mathcal{GP}(M(\mathbf{X}),C(\mathbf{X},\mathbf{X}))$, in which $M(\bullet)$ is the mean function and $C(\bullet,\bullet)$ is the covariance function. There is a term below:
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{E}_{\mathbf{X}_Q}=\int\limits_{\mathbf{X}_{-Q}} Y(\mathbf{X})\ d{\mathbf{X}_{-Q}}
\end{equation}
where $\mathbf{X}_{-Q}\cup\mathbf{X}_{Q}=\mathbf{X},\mathbf{X}_{-Q}\cap\mathbf{X}_{Q}=\emptyset$.

Some references said that $\mathbf{E}_{\mathbf{X}_Q}$ is also a Gaussian process with mean function
\begin{equation}
M'(\mathbf{X}_{Q})=\int\limits_{\mathbf{X}_{-Q}} M(\mathbf{X})\ d{\mathbf{X}_{-Q}}.
\end{equation}
and covariance function
\begin{equation}
C'(\mathbf{X}_{Q},\mathbf{X}'_{Q})=\int\limits_{\mathbf{X}_{-Q}}\,\,\, \int\limits_{\mathbf{X}'_{-Q}}C(\mathbf{X},\mathbf{X}'))\ d{\mathbf{X}_{-Q}}d{\mathbf{X}'_{-Q}}.
\end{equation}
How does the $\mathbf{E}_{\mathbf{X}_Q}$ hold a Gaussian distribution? I am not good at mathematics and statistics. Hope some one can leave a detailed explanation for that.